# How do I pass SSL Context into a Python Client that Uses the Autogenerated OpenAPI Python Client Library

Tags: python, ssl, openapi-generator

I have a Python3 OpenAPI client application that gives me the following error: "unable to get local issuer certificate".

This application uses the autogenerated python client libraries provided by the [OpenAPI generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator), and it connects to my HTTPS Node Express Service (stubs were also generated by the OpenAPI generator).

I am using version 5.4.0 of the OpenAPI Generator

I replicated the error with the following code snippet:

```
from urllib import request
resp = request.urlopen("https://sdbie-sargrad.chgme.com:8081/api-docs") 
html = resp.read()
```

I then fixed the error with the following update to this simple code snippet:

```
from urllib import request
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED 
context.load_verify_locations("/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem")
resp = request.urlopen("https://sdbie-sargrad.chgme.com:8081/api-docs", context=context) 
html = resp.read()
```

My OpenAPI code looks like the following:

```
from api.vlc_api_1_5_0.openapi_client.model.video import Video
from api.vlc_api_1_5_0.openapi_client.exceptions import ApiException
from api.vlc_api_1_5_0.openapi_client.exceptions import ApiTypeError
from api.vlc_api_1_5_0.openapi_client.configuration import Configuration
from api.vlc_api_1_5_0.openapi_client.api import video_api
from api.vlc_api_1_5_0.openapi_client.api_client import ApiClient

self.configuration = Configuration(host)
with ApiClient(self.configuration) as api_client:
    vid_api = video_api.VideoApi(api_client)
    try:
        inv = vid_api.get_video_inventory()
    except ApiException as e:
        self.logger.error("Exception when calling VideoApi->get_video_inventory: %s\n" % e)
```

As an aside the "[petstore api](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/samples/openapi3/client/petstore/python/petstore_api)" looks very much like the structure of the api that you see me using above.

How do I pass the appropriate SSL context (as seen in the fixed snippet above) into the constructor of the "VideoApi" that is autogenerated by the openapi generator?

Answer (score 0):

From the `urllib3` documentation, the best way to fix this issue cross-platform is by using the `certifi` library.

https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#certificate-verification

After installing `certifi` with `pip` you can pass ssl context to your `ApiClient()` via the `Configuration()` object.

```py
import certifi

# Your usual api imports here....

configuration = Configuration(host)

# NOTE: Here you pass the the path to the `cacert.pem` file
# containing the CA certificates for trusted hosts on PEM format.

configuration.ssl_ca_cert = certifi.where()

# Other configuration settings, like api token....

with ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    vid_api = video_api.VideoApi(api_client)
    try:
        inv = vid_api.get_video_inventory()
    except ApiException as e:
        self.logger.error("Exception when calling VideoApi->get_video_inventory: %s\n" % e)
```